# Emacs lisp code indentation

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

In emacs-lisp mode whenever i insert a closing brace i prefer to have indented to the same column like the corresponding opening brace. How is that possible? If i have eg in my init.el

```
(defadvice isearch-forward-regexp (before kill-ring-save-before-search activate)
  "Save region (if active) to kill-ring before starting isearch. So that region
can be inserted into isearch easily with C-y."
  (when (region-active-p)
    (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
    ) ;; this should be under (when
  ) ;; this should be under (defadvice
```

Comment: Don't do this. **Don’t make a habit of putting close-parentheses on lines by themselves; Lisp programmers find this disconcerting.** http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html

Comment: Please don't do this. It will make it harder for you to interchange code with other elisp writers.

Comment: The reason strings of "))))))" don't bother lisp programmers is they never count them.  The indentation is what matters and parentheses are always balanced because they use paredit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to align the close parens to be able to
visually match them to the opening ones.  You can do that with
`show-paren-mode` instead - it's much better at that job.

As pointed out by others, and I fully agree, the hanging parens are
very annoying and painful to look at - don't make a habit out of using
them. I've authored a minor mode for editing Elisp which might be
interesting for you - [lispy-mode](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy):

1. Pressing <kbd>i</kbd> will auto-indent an s-expression, eliminating
   the hanging parens.
2. Pressing <kbd>d</kbd> will switch from one side of s-expression to
   the other: a quick way to see what the current list contains.
3. Pressing <kbd>m</kbd> will toggle the region selection on the
   current list: you can see what it contains even more clearly.

Comment: Great tip! lispy-mode looks like a very nice mode for navigating lisp sources and deal with parenthesis. (However i have wonder where my square brackets are or how i can get them back...)

Comment: To insert `[]`, press **}**.